# Is there any way to conveniently generate an HTTP header for Winsock send(), instead of concatenating a string manually?

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

For example, instead of doing this:

```
char * buf = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n...";
sendRet = send( ClientSocket, buf, strlen(buf), 0 );
```

Something like this:

```
HttpHeader h;
h.Version = "1.0";
h.Status = "200 OK";
h.ContentType = HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_XML;
...
sendRet = send( ClientSocket, h.ToString(), h.Length(), 0 );
```

Comment: This is available for C++ http://httplib.codeplex.com/ if that is of any help

Comment: or [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want to stick to native windows

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly create your own `HttpHeader` to handle that, but you are still ultimately having to build up the HTTP header manually before passing it to `send()`, eg:

```
struct HttpHeader
{
    char *Version;
    char *Status;
    char *ContentType;
};

char* HttpHeaderToString(HttpHeader *hdr)
{
    int len = strlen(hdr->Version) + strlen(hdr->Status) + 10;
    if (strlen(hdr->ContentType) > 0)
        len += (strlen(hdr->ContentType) + 16);
    //...

    char *str = (char*) malloc(len);
    if (str != NULL)
    {        
        sprintf(str, "HTTP/%s %s\r\n", hdr->Version, hdr->Status);
        if (strlen(hdr->ContentType) > 0)
        {
            strcat(str, "Content-Type: ");
            strcat(str, hdr->ContentType);
            strcat(str, "\r\n");
        }
        //...
        strcat(str, "\r\n");
    }
    return str;
}
```

```
HttpHeader h;
h.Version = "1.0";
h.Status = "200 OK";
h.ContentType = HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_XML;
...
char *str = HttpHeaderToString(&h);
if (str != NULL)
{
    send(ClientSocket, str, strlen(str), 0);
    free(str);
}
```

On the other hand, TCP is a byte stream, so you don't have to send everything in a single `send()` call. You can call `send()` as many times as you need, eg (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
void SendHttpHeader(HttpHeader *hdr)
{
    send(ClientSocket, "HTTP/", 5, 0);
    send(ClientSocket, hdr->Version, strlen(hdr->Version), 0);
    send(ClientSocket, " ", 1, 0);
    send(ClientSocket, hdr->Status, strlen(hdr->Status), 0);
    send(ClientSocket, "\r\n", 2, 0);
    if (strlen(hdr->ContentType) > 0)
    {
        send(ClientSocket, "Content-Type: ", 14, 0);
        send(ClientSocket, hdr->ContentType, strlen(hdr->ContentType), 0);
        send(ClientSocket, "\r\n", 2, 0);
    }
    //...
    send(ClientSocket, "\r\n", 2, 0);
 }
```

```
HttpHeader h;
h.Version = "1.0";
h.Status = "200 OK";
h.ContentType = HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_XML;
...
SendHttpHeader(&h);
```

Comment: This is C++ - The question is tagged C. That is why I left it as a comment

Comment: The OP's question showed `h.ToString()` and `h.Length()`, which will not work in C as it does not support classes, or methods in records.  It is not uncommon to tag a C++ question as C, or to use a C++ compiler to write C code.  It is not that hard to translate my examples into C if C++ is not actually being used. That does not change the core gist of my answer. But whatever, I will re-write the answer in C.

Comment: Are you sure that `h.ToString()` will not work in C - Consider http://codepad.org/CXa3O67c

Comment: @EdHeal: In this situation, that would not work as-is. The function being pointed at would need to have the `struct` passed to it as an input parameter so it knows what data to operate on. That is no different than simply calling a standalone function instead, as shown in my example. Remember, there is no `this` pointer in C. It would be odd to have to write `h.ToString(&h)`, don't you think?